# BarLegend color usage indicator

Tags: plotting, legending

```
$Version
DensityPlot3D[x y z
 , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}
 , ColorFunction -> Hue
 , ImageSize -> 200
 , PlotLegends -> {BarLegend[Hue
    , LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 180}]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

**Question**

1. What is the proper name for the gray area to the left of `BarLegend`? My guess is that it is trying to convey the range of colors used in the plot.
2. A `Legended` plot does not have this gray area (just a `BarLegend`). Is this a feature of `PlotLegends`?
3. Is there an option to turn it off?
4. Is there an option to change its width and/or style?
5. Any link to its documentation would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's the opacity of the color. See Details and Options in [`DensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
KeySelect[MatchQ[_String?(StringMatchQ["Opac*"])]]@ Options[Charting`iBarLegend]
```

> ```
> <|"OpacityFunctionTicks" -> None,
>   "OpacityFunctionSize" -> Automatic, 
>   "OpacityFunctionRange" -> {0, 1}, 
>   "OpacityColorFunction" -> GrayLevel[0.4]|>
> ```

```
BarLegend[Hue, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 180}, 
  "OpacityFunctionTicks" -> All,
  "OpacityFunctionSize" -> Scaled[2], 
  "OpacityColorFunction" -> Red, 
  OpacityFunction -> 
    ((If[Inequality[9/22, LessEqual, -1. + 2.*#1, Less, 7/11], 0.01, 
        0.5, 0] & )[Rescale[#1, {0, 1}, {0.5, 1}]] & ), 
  Charting`TickSide -> Right]
```

[image]

```
BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {-1, 1}}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 300}, 
 "OpacityFunctionTicks" -> {{0, "zero"}, {.5, "1/2"}, {1, "one"}}, 
 "OpacityFunctionSize" -> Scaled[1],
 "OpacityColorFunction" -> Black, 
 OpacityFunction -> (Rescale[Abs[#1 - 1/2], {0, 1/2}, {0, 1}] &), 
 Charting`TickSide -> Right]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot3D[x y z, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 200, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Hue,
    "OpacityFunction" -> None, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 180}]]
```

[image]